# How to check if a table exists in MS Access for vb macros

Tags: ms-access, vba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if access table exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985513/check-if-access-table-exists)

I'm new to vba macros. Any idea how to check if a table exists or not?
I have searched for previous posts but did not get a clear solution for this.

Comment: While it implicitly is related, since checking if a table exists will require looking at the members of a collection, it's hardly a duplicate.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Setting a reference to the Microsoft Access 12.0 Object Library allows us to test if a table exists using DCount.

```
Public Function ifTableExists(tblName As String) As Boolean

    If DCount("[Name]", "MSysObjects", "[Name] = '" & tblName & "'") = 1 Then

        ifTableExists = True

    End If

End Function
```

Comment: The problem with this method is that it will return True for linked tables with a non working back-end. Using DCount would be much slower, but more reliable.

Comment: Another problem is that it also seems to find forms and reports...
    ifTableExists("myFormName")
returns true

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I knew about the dCount function, but didn't know how to sent a **variable** (tableName) to it. Thanks. One small problem that can cause bugs: You changed the returned value directly each time. what you should do is `dim b as Boolean  b=False  If...b=True  End If   ifTableExists = b End Function`

Answer (score 14):

I know the question is already answered, but I find that the existing answers are not valid:
they will return True for linked tables with a non working back-end.
Using DCount can be much slower, but is more reliable.

```
Function IsTable(sTblName As String) As Boolean
    'does table exists and work ?
    'note: finding the name in the TableDefs collection is not enough,
    '      since the backend might be invalid or missing

    On Error GoTo hell
    Dim x
    x = DCount("*", sTblName)
    IsTable = True
    Exit Function
hell:
    Debug.Print Now, sTblName, Err.Number, Err.Description
    IsTable = False

End Function
```

Answer (score 13):

```
Exists = IsObject(CurrentDb.TableDefs(tablename))
```

Comment: how can i use this? 
 
I used like this,

 Exists = IsObject(CurrentDb.TableDefs("& ConctNmeforDB &"))
         
         MsgBox Exists


After that, i got run time error as 3265.  Item Not Found in this collection.

Comment: Practically speaking, you can't use it by itself. It has to be wrapped in an error handler so that it returns false when it encounters error 3265. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985513/check-if-access-table-exists/2992743#2992743 for 3 different implementations of a TableExists() function.

Answer (score 2):

Access has some sort of system tables [You can read about it a little here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3528491) you can fire the folowing query to see if it exists ( 1 = it exists, 0 = it doesnt ;))

```
SELECT Count([MSysObjects].[Name]) AS [Count]
FROM MSysObjects
WHERE (((MSysObjects.Name)="TblObject") AND ((MSysObjects.Type)=1));
```

Comment: That will miss linked tables, type=4.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a new question. I addresed it in [comments in one SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909371/access-create-table-if-it-does-not-exist/911493#911493), and posted [my alternative implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985513/check-if-access-table-exists/2992743#2992743) in another post. The comments in the first post actually elucidate the performance differences between the different implementations.

Basically, which works fastest depends on what database object you use with it.