# MS Access/ VBA : add if condition to vba code

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have the following code :

```
Private Sub Command66_Click()
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "Table1"
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "Table2"
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "Table3"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

The problem is that if "Table1" is not present,I receive an VBA/debug Error. Can I add some condition that if the script doesn't find "Table1" it should go further and delete the other 2 tables without returning any error message?

Comment: See if it exists first: [how to check if table is exists or not in ms access for vb macros?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350645/how-to-check-if-table-is-exists-or-not-in-ms-access-for-vb-macros)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean error trapping? Here's an example of how you can "trap" an error - If an error occured trying to delete Table1 it will ask you if you want to continue:

```
Private Sub Command66_Click()
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

On Error Resume Next
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "Table1"

If Err.Number > 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
    If MsgBox("There was an error trying to delete Table1, do you want to continue?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "Table2"
        DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "Table3"
    End If
End If
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If you decide to trap and ignore the error, start by ignoring *only* error 7874 (*Microsoft Access can't find the object ''.*)  You may prefer not to ignore other errors, such as when the table is in use.

```vb
Private Sub Command66_Click()

    Dim strMsg As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "Table1"
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "Table2"
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "Table3"

ExitHere:
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case 7874 'Microsoft Access can't find the object
        Resume Next
    Case Else
        strMsg = "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description _
            & ") in procedure Command66_Click"
        MsgBox strMsg
        GoTo ExitHere
    End Select
End Sub
```

Notes:

- If you discover other errors you wish to ignore, you can add those error numbers to the first `Case` statement: `Case 7874, <another number here>`
- I don't see any reason to turn `SetWarnings` off in this procedure.
- Consider Alex's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042112/ms-access-vba-add-if-condition-to-vba-code#comment57808901_35042112) to check whether the table exists before attempting to delete it.

Answer (score -1):

Well, if you want to delete table that only exists in Access then you can simply check for the object, here is how you normally do it:

```
On Error Resume Next
If IsObject(CurrentDb.TableDefs("Table1")) Then
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "Table1"
End If
```

Comment: did you put On Error Resume Next before if statement?